# I need to set up Linux Mint for visually impaired user BIG FONT EVERYWHERE

Tags: linux, fonts, linux-mint

How can I change the base font for the operating system so that everything is 200% and it still makes a usable screen?
There must be a setting somehwere that takes effect in all programs, menus, text...

Answer (score 3):

The quick general fix all solution could be to change to a smaller screen resolution on a larger monitor.

Comment: Yup. Trying to randomly push font sizes is going to make things not fit their assigned boxes; text-spill. Changing screen-res is idiot-proof.